# How To Set Cookies for JWT in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, express, json-web-token

I am trying to simply set the `cookie` for the `JSON Web Token` during authentication in my `Node.js` and `Express` web application.

Since I cannot do `res.redirect` after using `res.cookie()`, how can I achieve this?

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (!user) { return res.redirect('/auth'); }
        var theToken = jwt.encode({ id : user.id }, req.app.get('appSecret'));

        res.cookie(theToken);

        return res.redirect('/profile/' + username);

    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Am I approaching this problem correctly? I cannot find much of anything on how people are setting their `JSON Web Token`s once they have created them.

Comment: Why do you want to use cookies and tokens? That would defeat the main benefit of JWTs (no sessions)

Comment: Main benefit was to keep a RESTful design and decouple the server from the client.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `res.redirect` works with setting the cookies, despite what some other SO answers state. Hopefully this helps someone else.